# Is "lower" being used correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Can lower be used in the following fashion?

> 1000 yen said the first price tag. 750 the second one. The **lower**
>   number of the latter shocked me.

If not, what's a better alternative?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Why do you prefer your version over mine? I'm curious.

Comment: You may use your sentence if you prefer, no problem.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the use of "lower" in that sentence, but It's far from idiomatic in English, and would be better phrased as _"That the latter number was lower shocked me"_ or _"I was shocked that the latter was lower!"_

Comment: Why use *number* when you are talking about prices? Instead "The lower *price* of/on the latter *one* shocked me."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest only one slight change of wording:

1000 yen said the first price tag. 750 the second one. The lower number **on** the latter shocked me.

"number of" would suggest a quantity of price tags, not a price ON the price tag.

NOTE ALSO: It is incorrect to begin a sentence with a numeric value AND, your second sentence is incomplete.

SO, the final version would be:

One Thousand yen said the first price tag; seven hundred fifty said the second one. The lower number on the latter shocked me.